# How to find element by type using protractor

Tags: types, protractor

i have

```
            input type="text"
```

It changes on buttnonClick to

```
             type="password"
```

How to check the type changes

Tried :

```
             var inputType = element(by.css('input.MyValue').clear();
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand the problem. This is what I understood:

```
// Text is present, but password is not.
expect($('[type=text]').isPresent()).toBe(true);
expect($('[type=password]').isPresent()).toBe(false);

$('button').click();

// Now the password is present, but not the input
expect($('[type=text]').isPresent()).toBe(false);
expect($('[type=password]').isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a page with 2 inputs one type text and another with type password:

```
let list = await element.all(by.tagName('input'));

// get 1st input, type text
expect(list[0].isPresent()).toBe(true);
expect(list[0].getAttribute('type')).toEqual('text');
expect(list[0].getAttribute('placeholder')).toEqual('Email');

// get 2nd input, type password
expect(list[1].isPresent()).toBe(true);
expect(list[1].getAttribute('type')).toEqual('password');
expect(list[1].getAttribute('placeholder')).toEqual('Password');
```

and do whatever you need to do with each element.